# Geometric formulation of the subject of machine learning

Tags: soft-question, machine-learning

> **Question:**
>
> what is the geometric interpretation of the subject of machine learning and/or deep learning?

Being "forced" to have a closer look at the subject, I have the impression that it all boils down to approximately reconstruct the characteristic function that decides about set-membership of the points of the feature space.

To me the essential "innovation" seems to be that a function must calculated on basis of the signum of its values for a certain sample of coordinates, that resemble the "training" set.

Say we are given finite sets $C\subset\mathcal{C}$ and $D\subset\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ my impression is that the goal is to find a function, whose zero-set partitions the feature space so that the signum of the function values complies with characteristic function of $\mathcal{C}$ with high probability; is that impression right?

**Addendum:**  
my final "working assumption" about what Machine Learning, resp. Deep Learning is actually about, is to play a sophisticated version of [battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) in disguise.  
The analogues of the ship geometries are more complicated shapes also in higher dimensions and spaces with non-euclidean distance metrics.
The whole subject of research is to devise methods to sink the opponent's ships faster.

Comment: What makes you look for a geometric interpretation of the subject of machine learning? This is unclear to me from your post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis e.g. Decision Trees amount to partitioning of Data Space; Support Vector Machines look for separating maifolds, Principal Component Analysis amounts to a rotation of Data Space; Manifold Learning is obviously geometrically motivated.

Comment: It appears then that your comment answers your question, except that, instead of "the geometric interpretation" you have different geometric interpretations for different tools. Are you then looking for one all-encompassing interpretation?

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, ideally I would like a high level description of the subject using only terminology from geometry, maybe with resemblance to statistics to account for uncertainty or fuzzyness.

Comment: Machine learning (at least supervised machine learning) is essentially part of statistics. Why do you want it to get divorced/separated from statistics, leaving there at best a resemblance to what it naturally is part of?

Comment: @IosifPinelis it is not my intent to divorce it from statistics and I acknowledge that statistics may be the theory that yields the best results, but statistics are applied to estimate set member ship and my question may be interpreted as aimed at describing what it is to which the statistic are applied.

Comment: does the kernel trick / reproducing kernel hilbert space count as geometry?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser I would say: definitely yes. In the case of separating hyperplanes it can be calculated via nearest points of convex hulls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several geometric aspects of machine learning.

1. You can think of the goal of ML as function approximation. Your question mentions reconstructing a characteristic function, but people often look at approximating other types of functions as well ("regression" as opposed to "classification"). The geometry here comes from defining what approximation means, i.e., the "loss function."
2. Many models (i.e., members of a parameterized family of functions) themselves have a natural kind of geometry: that is, you can look at distances between models based on their parameters, rather than the functions they compute. A Riemannian metric on parameters is useful in defining gradients for the learning process.
3. In deep learning, one often looks at representations of data in a geometric way. A classic example is word embeddings, which associate words with points in a high-dimensional space, so that geometric operations (say, addition and subtraction) correspond to meaningful linguistic operations (say, analogical reasoning).

Taking a geometric point of view on ML is incredibly powerful! That said, it's also just one part of the subject, and thinking of ML only in terms of pure geometry is like thinking of probability only in terms of measure theory: not technically wrong, but not always the most helpful viewpoint.